# What is the purpose of connecting your reference ground plane to earth when doing radiated emissions testing?

Tags: ground, emc, earth

In most standards it's required to connect the reference ground plane to earth.

However in a lot of cases the reference ground plane is elevated above the earth by a set height.

If you left the earth wire out of a set up where the reference ground plane is lifted off the actual earth ground would that change the radiated emissions results?

One possible difference I can imagine is that the earth wire can act as an antenna and add noise to the reference ground plane. This might make results difficult to standardize. Ignoring this possibility and the requirement for safety in high voltage systems, what is connecting the reference ground plane to earth actually doing to the radiated emissions measurement results?

Answer (score 0):

> If you left the earth wire out of a set up where the reference ground plane is lifted off the actual earth ground would that change the radiated emissions results?

In short, yes. Any change to emissions testing setups will change the outcome. Emissions testing is horrendously complex, where a seemingly insignificant change to the device setup, the test setup or even where the technician is standing can lead to drastic changes in the performance of the EUT.

> One possible difference I can imagine is that the earth wire can act as an antenna and add noise to the reference ground plane. This might make results difficult to standardize. Ignoring this possibility and the requirement for safety in high voltage systems, what is connecting the reference ground plane to earth actually doing to the radiated emissions measurement results?

I could just as easily 'imagine' that without the earth wire attached, the entire plane will couple horrendously and make the whole thing worse. The point is its very hard to try to predict the test outcome from a given change to a test setup. I would argue that trying to imagine what might happen to a system (without being an EMC consultant who lives and breathes this stuff) is useless without verifying it through testing, and design decisions based on these imaginings is bad practice.

Connecting the reference ground plane to earth *is* standardising the results.